# Internal compiler error: Could not load type NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration

Tags: .net, nhibernate, mono, monodevelop

I'm referencing the NHibernate dll version 2.1.2-GA, and am unable to compile under Mono 2.8.1. I've tried using NHibernate 3 instead and it compiles fine.

A simple example of the code that's failing is

> NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

and the error is

> Error CS0584: Internal compiler error:
>   Could not load type
>   'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' from
>   assembly 'NHibernate,
>   Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4'.
>   (CS0584)

As mentioned it compiles with no problems using NHibernate 3, does anyone have any ideas how to get it working with NHiberate 2.1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is to do with compiling in MonoDevelop rather than a problem with NHibernate, as I could build in Visual Studio, copy the binaries to Linux and run it successfully. While I still can't compile using MonoDevelop, compiling in Visual Studio and copying the binaries across is a sufficient work around for my needs.